# Vaadin Context Menu Add-on Error

Tags: java, contextmenu, vaadin, add-on

I've trying to get this to work now for 4 hours - the problem is that Vaadin shows me a error the way I am implementing it:

> *Widgetset com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet' does not contain implementation for org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.ContextMenu. Check its component connector's @Connect mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you might want to refer to add-on instructions.*

I already tried to re-compile it - no errors while compiling.
I use Vaadin 7 and the Addon Version 4.4.0

> https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/69

any suggestion's?

Comment: How do you compile your widgetset? Can you see the mentioned addon in the compiler log?

Comment: I press on 'Compile Widgetset', yes I can see it.

Comment: then you have not configured the widgetset?  e.g. https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/addons.maven.html `Enabling the Widget Set in the UI`

Comment: I have no plan how to do this.. dont know the package of the widget., could u write a answere?

Comment: at least intellij autocompletes the gwt packages.  not sure about other IDEs.  yet finding the xml in the jar of the addon should not be to hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you have used the vaadin-archetype-application to create the project, the pom.xml includes all necessary declarations to compile the widget set. The widget set compilation occurs in standard Maven build phase, such as with package or install goal.

```
$ mvn package
```

The Vaadin plugin for Maven tries to avoid recompiling the widget set unless necessary, which sometimes means that it is not compiled even when it should. Running the clean goal usually helps, but causes a full recompilation. You can compile the widget set manually by running the vaadin:compile goal.

```
$ mvn vaadin:compile
```

Note that this does not update the project widget set by searching new widget sets from the class path. It must be updated if you add or remove add-ons, for example. You can do that by running the vaadin:update-widgetset goal in the project directory.

```
$ mvn vaadin:update-widgetset
```

**Do not mind the "ERROR" labels,**

they are just an issue with the Vaadin Plugin for Maven.
After running the update, you need to run the vaadin:compile goal to actually compile the widget set.

**Enabling the Widget Set in the UI**
If you have previously used the default widget set in the project, you need to enable the project widget set in the web.xml deployment descriptor. Edit the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml file and add or modify the widgetset parameter for the servlet as follows

```
<servlet>
  ...      
<init-param>
            <description>Context Menue</description>
            <param-name>contextMenue</param-name>
            <param-value>org.vaadin.peter.contextmenu.ContextmenuWidgetset</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Don't forget to `clean`: `mvn clean package`